# Why is python code running but there is no output when using equation?

Tags: python, output, equation

I wrote a code that works great for solving equations numerically, but there is I a specific equation that when I get in there and try running the code - it will run and no output will ever come out!

Equation I got an output for: x^3−3*x+2−a*(np.sin(x))

Equation I didn't get an output for: (x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3)-a*(np.cos(x))

I also tried writing the second equation without brackets, like this: x^3-6*x^2+11*x-6-a*np.cos(x)

and it didn't help. **where is the problem?!**

this is my code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
h =1e-5
eps =1e-8
#function of the equation
def nf(x,a,c):
    c=math.cos(x)
    solu=(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3)-a*c
    return(solu)
#numerical method
def sl(a,x):
    c=math.cos(x)    
    f = nf(x,a,c)
    while abs(f)>eps:
        x = x - h*f/(nf(x+h,a,c)-f)
        f = nf(x,a,c)
    return(x)

N = 101
mya = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,N)
myb = np.zeros(mya.shape)
myc = np.zeros(mya.shape)
myd = np.zeros(mya.shape)
for i in range(0,N):
    myb[i] = sl(mya[i],1.0)
    myc[i] = sl(mya[i],2.0)
    myd[i] = sl(mya[i],3.0)

print(myb[i])
print(myc[i])
print(myd[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for some input to `sl`, `abs(f)>eps` might not ever become `False`, creating an infinite loop. I havn't investigated the mathematical problem of yours, so I can't solve this problem "for real". What I can provide is automatic detection of when this happens, so that the code returns without a result rather than looping forever.

```
def sl(a,x):
    c=math.cos(x)    
    f = nf(x,a,c)
    count, maxcount = 0, 1000
    while abs(f)>eps:
        x = x - h*f/(nf(x+h,a,c)-f)
        f = nf(x,a,c)
        count += 1
        if count > maxcount:
            return
    return(x)
```

Here, a maximum of `1000` iterations is allowed before a solution is deemed unreachable. In such a case, `sl` returns `None`, which when inserted into your NumPy `float` arrays becomes `np.nan`.

Upon investigating the output, only `myc[60]` fails in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your nf function was a little weird. You were passing `c = math.cos(x)` into nf() but whithin nf() you tried to assign `c to math.cos(x)` again. Just use the value `c` what you passed. Commenting it out fixes your code. As for the mathematical correctness, I cannot determine that unless you provide a better explanation what youre trying to do.

```
import math
import numpy as np
h =1e-5
eps =1e-8
#function of the equation
def nf(x,a,c): 
    # this line is not needed. Commenting allows your code to run   
#     c=math.cos(x)
    solu=(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3)-a*c
    return(solu)
#numerical method
def sl(a,x):  
    c = math.cos(x)
    f = nf(x,a,c)
    while abs(f)>eps:
        x = x - h*f/(nf(x+h,a,c)-f)
        f = nf(x,a,c)
    return(x)

N = 101
mya = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,N)
myb = np.zeros(mya.shape)
myc = np.zeros(mya.shape)
myd = np.zeros(mya.shape)
for i in range(0,N):
    myb[i] = sl(mya[i],1.0)
    myc[i] = sl(mya[i],2.0)
    myd[i] = sl(mya[i],3.0)

print(myb[i])
print(myc[i])
print(myd[i])
```

**Output:**

```
3.2036907284
0.835006605064
0.677633820877
```